# Payout to User's External account bank account gives 'No such External Account...'

Tags: c#, api, stripe-payments

I have a very frustrating problem and Stripe's documentation/customer service have been giving me the run-around and my question is still not resolved.

I am trying to implement a payout programmatically in C# to a user's bank account.

Amounts are accumulated in one stripe account (my account) but users have 'balances' that our backend keeps track of. When a user decides they want to be paid out, this is where I am running into an issue.

So far, this is what i've implemented:

1. Create the User's external account and attach a bank account:
   https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create
2. Create a payout object:
   https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create

But the problem occurs when I create a payout and add a destination to that payout. The reason for this is because a user might have more than one bank account linked to their external account.

I have something like this:

Create an external account for user

```
Account userCustomAccount = await account.CreateAsync(new AccountCreateOptions()
{
    Type = "custom",
    DefaultCurrency = "usd",
    Country = "US",
    Email = "user@fake.com",
    LegalEntity = new AccountLegalEntityOptions() {...},
    ExternalBankAccount = new AccountBankAccountOptions()
    {
        AccountHolderType = "individual",
        AccountNumber = "123456789",
        RoutingNumber = "987654321,
        Currency = "usd",
        Country = "US",
        AccountHolderName = "Test User"
    },
    TosAcceptance = new AccountTosAcceptanceOptions(){...},
    PayoutSchedule = new AccountPayoutScheduleOptions()
    {
        Interval = "manual"
    },
    PayoutStatementDescriptor = "TEST"
});
```

Create a payout

```
var sourcePayout = new PayoutCreateOptions()
{
    Amount = 100,
    Currency = "usd",
    Destination = bankAccountId,
    SourceType = "bank_account",
    StatementDescriptor = "PAYOUT"
};
```

where `bankAccountId` is the id (`like ba_xxxx`) that I retrieved from `userCustomAccount.ExternalAccounts`

I get an error when attempting to call payout saying that "No such external account exists"

Any idea how to resolve this? I don't understand why this is so difficult to do and why this is giving me so much trouble.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

since you are creating `payout` to the connected account from your `platform` account, you will need to use the `Stripe-Account` header

What you are doing now is creating a payout for your own account with the connected account's bank id.

in C#, you would need to use the `requestOptions`

```
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.StripeConnectAccountId = "CONNECTED ACCOUNT ID"; 

.... 
....
var payout = await PayoutService.CreateAsync(sourcePayout, requestOptions);
```

The key things is whenever you are operating on your `connected account` other than creating account itself, such as creating charge, payout, creating customer on connected account, you will need to pass the `Stripe-Account` header.

- (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet#request-options)
- (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#using-manual-payouts)

Comment: thanks @wsw I tried this but i got an error:
`Insufficient funds in Stripe account. In test mode, you can add funds to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance) by creating a charge with 4000 0000 0000 0077 as the card number.   You can use the the /v1/balance endpoint to view your Stripe balance (for more details, see stripe.com/docs/api#balance).`
My main account has available funds but the connected account has 0. I'm not sure what is going on here. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, `payout` in Stripe means moving fund from `Account Balance` to physical `Bank Account`. 
Since you are creating a `Manual` payout for the connected account, it means you are moving `Available Balance` from your Connected Account Balance to its registered bank account. 
The connected account needs to have `Available Balance` in order to `payout` aka cashing out. 
What you could do is to using the card mentioned and create a `Direct Charge` with the account header following (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges), this will give funds to the connected account

Comment: Thanks, @wsw for your answer, I know this question is for a long time, but I have a question regarding this solution,  when we set `Stripe-Account` and the external connected account will payout itself that means it will use the platform account balance to payout itself right?

Answer (score 1):

if you are creating payout from platform to connect account's external account, directly it might not be done. first send the fund from platform balance to connect account using transfer api. [transfer api](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create).

and then create a payout on the connect account. generally the payouts are automatic, and after the preset minimum number of days(for US 2 days), the payout is created with all the available balance in the connect account balance.